# How to display averages in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I am working on a line chart. I have many readings for 1 day and I need to display data for 30 days. How can I display the average for each day instead of showing every data points?

Comment: You can calculate the average of each day and store that as an array of data and then just plot that series of data.

Comment: Is there any way I can do it in highcharts itself?

Comment: You can define an anonymous function within your series of data that calculates the average.

Comment: Thank you.do you have any examples?

Comment: Here is one that calculates the average upon a zoom in on the graph --> http://jsfiddle.net/yuKwp/4/ You should be able to modify it for your series data. I still believe the easiest way however is to calculate the averages, populate an array with those averages, and then plot that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `datetime` xAxis you can use `Highstock` and use the `dataGrouping` property for that:

```
plotOptions: {
        line: {
            enabled: true,
            forced: true,
            dataGrouping: {
                approximation: 'average',
                units: [
                    [
                        'month', [1]]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

This will automatically group your daily data to average of month. Here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d90gc590/)

Comment: Thanks this helped me